# Eclipse MAT shows no stack for many threads

Tags: java, memory-leaks, eclipse-memory-analyzer, eclipse-mat

I have a leak in my code, and I've got a memory dump that I'm looking at with the awesome Eclipse Memory Analyzer tool.

Using the Thread_Overview, I can see that I have too many threads.  However, only a few show stacks.  The bulk of them (which are probably my leaks) show a status of 2 (BLOCKED), yet have no stacks.

Any idea what it means when there's no stack in the dump? Perhaps the thread is dead, but the reference is still kept in memory (ie. a leak)?

(Java 6 on Windows 2K if if makes any difference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the thread has terminated. That's why no stack.

What threw me was this: the status of 2 is NOT blocked, but terminated.  This is because the field `threadStatus` is a bit field that's decoded by `sun.misc.VM.toThreadState()`. I thought threadStatus was the thread state enum, but it's not. You have to read that method to see what the real state is.  On windows, it's this:

```
public static Thread.State toThreadState(int paramInt)
{
 if ((paramInt & 0x4) != 0)
   return Thread.State.RUNNABLE;
 if ((paramInt & 0x400) != 0)
   return Thread.State.BLOCKED;
 if ((paramInt & 0x10) != 0)
   return Thread.State.WAITING;
 if ((paramInt & 0x20) != 0)
   return Thread.State.TIMED_WAITING;
 if ((paramInt & 0x2) != 0)
   return Thread.State.TERMINATED;
 if ((paramInt & 0x1) == 0) {
   return Thread.State.NEW;
 }
 return Thread.State.RUNNABLE;
}
```

So, the when `threadStatus` is 2, it means the thread's been terminated.